# Why rendering image in code behind do not work?

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to generate screenshot from helix control but only in code behind - why this not work?
Something is missing?

```c#
private void generate() {

    ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
    Model3D model = importer.Load(@"c:\test\test.obj");

    Model3DGroup group = new Model3DGroup();
    group.Children.Add(model);

    ModelVisual3D myModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
    myModelVisual3D.Content = group;

    HelixViewport3D viewer = new HelixViewport3D();
    viewer.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(1024, 768, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                bmp.Render(viewer);

                PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bmp);
                png.Frames.Add(frame);
                using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"c:\test\test.png"))
                {
                    png.Save(stm);
                }            }
            ), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
}
```

**Edit:**

No exceptions - nothing - code seams to be working but PNG is empty. If I swap `HelixViewport3D viewer` with control that is in XAML then PNG is generated ok. With HelixViewport3D defined in code rendering is not working and PNG is empty - size is ok - it is PNG but no content - transparent when I display it.
In this test.obj file is nothing special - when I use XAML defined HelixViewport3D - all is ok.

Comment: So what *does* happen? Is there an exception? Just "not work" doesn't tell us much at all about what you can see, or what diagnostic steps you've taken to work out what's going on.

Comment: No exceptions - nothing - code seams to be working but PNG is empty. If I swap HelixViewport3D viewer with control that is in XAML then PNG is generated ok. With HelixViewport3D defined in code rendering is not working and PNG is empty.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate that - with more detail. By "empty" do you mean the file has a content length of 0, or that it's a 0x0 valid image, or that it's an image of the right size, but with no content?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but it was not easy for me too to find a satisfying solution.

The main reason I see is that you did not attach the viewport to a window.
If like me you don't want to see any window at all there are two solutions:

1. Hacky solution

- Put the viewport in a window
- Set the window style to the following:

```xml
    <Style x:Key="EdgeToEdgeWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
      <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
      <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="Left" Value="-10000" />
      <Setter Property="Top" Value="-10000" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
            <AdornerDecorator>
              <ContentPresenter />
            </AdornerDecorator>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

2. Clean solution
   Use the class HostVisual the following way

```cs
this.hostVisual = new HostVisual();
this.visualTargetPS = new VisualTargetPresentationSource(hostVisual);
this.renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
this.visualTargetPS.RootVisual = this.viewport;
```

There won't be any rendering loop, but you can manually trigger a rendering calling `this.viewport.InvalidateRender();`
Then everytime you want to save a rendering just call this:

```cs
this.renderTargetBitmap.Render(this.viewport);
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
using (var stream = new FileStream(this.currentJob.ThumbnailPath, FileMode.Create))
{
 encoder.Save(stream);
}
```